# Configuring Shell Environment for Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, oracle, powershell

Configure the shell environment for the CDB (orcl) and set the TWO_TASK variable to the PDB (pdborcl)

```
 . oraenv
 export TWO_TASK=pdborcl
 sqlplus sys/password as sysdba
```

I got the link from [here](https://community.oracle.com/message/11234394#11234394)

The above instructions are vital to enable me install sample HR schema on my oracle 12c database(Home PC) for training on Windows 8.1.

I have tried running the commands using the prefix SET in windows power-shell and CMD (admin privileges) but no positive results.

I am aware that in order to set the TWO_TASK....I can achieve this by setting these parameters in windows environment or using CMD.

UPDATE WITH SOME CODE:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> SET oraenv
C:\WINDOWS\system32> SET export TWO_TASK=pdborcl
C:\WINDOWS\system32> SET sqlplus sys/1Ihavenone as sysdba
Set-Variable : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'as'.
At line:1 char:1
  + SET sqlplus sys/1Masupalami as sysdba
  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Variable], ParameterBindingException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetVariableCommand
```

1Ihavenone sys password and works fine in connect to CDB$ROOT –

Comment: Can you add some of the output from the power shell?

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32> SET oraenv
C:\WINDOWS\system32> SET export TWO_TASK=pdborcl
C:\WINDOWS\system32> SET sqlplus sys/1Ihavenone as sysdba
Set-Variable : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'as'.
At line:1 char:1
+ SET sqlplus sys/1Masupalami as sysdba
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Variable], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetVariableCommand

1Ihavenone sys password and works fine in connect to CDB$ROOT

Comment: NOTE: I can connect to CDB in sqlplus Even alter session to PDBORCL successful using sys as sysdba

Comment: Unfortunately, the link you followed was for a UNIX/Linux version of sqlnet, not windows.